# Not being able to set property in form using jquery

Tags: jquery, upload, image-uploading

**Browser**: Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.108 ), Firefox: 71.0 (32-bit)

**Jquery**: 3.3.1

I am trying to upload an image using jquery.
So, I tried to use the FormData and set a field with the blob value. Reference source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set

In the debugger, I found that I am not being able to set any field. Please see the screenshot from the console for a similar example.

[image]

Any insight or idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the return type of set which is something different then what you expect. After setting the value please get using the get method of formdata.

```
var data = new FormData();
//This will return undefined
data.set("a","b");
// This will return the actual value which is "b"
data.get('a');
```